# Is self-calling functions in Javascript harmful?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, call

I have a Javascript function that is calling itself for purpose of refreshing notification bar. My function is like:

```
function refreshLoop() {
      refresh();
      setTimeout("refreshLoop();", 10000);
}
```

My question is that if I use that function like this, will be there any harm -programming error-. I am asking this question because you see refreshLoop() function never ends.

Should I use it like this or do you have any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That's not recursive.

Comment: For this specific case, you can use `setInterval()`.

Comment: Also, this indeed isn't recursion. `setTimeout()` means the function should be called on the browser page's *event loop* in 10 seconds. For that to happen, the current event that sets the timeout must necessarily finish executing.

Comment: No, this is not harmful. This is perfectly fine.

Comment: If the OP switches to setInterval() the calling pattern will need to change as well so that it calls refresh not refreshLoop.

Answer (score 3):

This construct is frequent and fine (especially if a conditional call of `setTimeout` makes it hard to use `setInterval`), but it's not written as you did. Don't eval code when you can directly pass the function. Use this :

```
function refreshLoop() {
      refresh();
      setTimeout(refreshLoop, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can end the timeout loop by removing the timeout like that:

```
var timeout;

function refreshLoop() {
  refresh();
  timeout = setTimeout(refreshLoop, 1000);
}

refreshLoop()

// later on
clearTimeout(timeout)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong with it, but you could lose the eval "refreshLoop();"

```
function refreshLoop() {
  refresh();
  setTimeout(refreshLoop, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Why write a second identical answer ?

Comment: Cuz. **R.E.P.** @dystroy

Comment: There was no answer when I started writing my answer.  I'll be sure to check new answer alert next time.